# D3 Translate Value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a D3 project right now, and the following code WORKS but I don't understand why.

When translating (moving) the position of a Y-Scale of an area chart (in this example it is the yAxis variable that I call in the last line of code) I should enter in the value of the transform attribute surrounded by two "+" icons. Why is this value broken up with quotation marks and what is the purpose of the + icons? If someone could break down the last line of code that would be very helpful.

```
var margin = {left: 50, right: 50, top: 40, bottom: 0};

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([0, 229])
.range([height, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis y").call(yAxis)
.attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+",200)").call(yAxis);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` is string concatenation*. In your case, `"translate("+margin.left+",200)"` is changed to `"translate(50,200)"` because margin.left === 50.

*or, more appropriately the add function for strings.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Is that unique to D3 or used in javascript more widely?

Comment: Javascript in general. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition